# Filtering thredds datasetScan by both directory and file pattern?

Tags: thredds

In THREDDS server setup, I need to configure datasetScan filter element in catalog.xml so that it takes into account full file path, not just file name or directory name. Say, I have following folder structure:

```
/GGG/alpha/a
          /b
          /c
/GGG/beta/a
         /b
         /c
```

And I want to remove a file named `a` only from folder `alpha`. I can remove the file `a` from both folders by setting

```
<exclude wildcard="a"/>
```

or I can remove the folder `alpha` completely by setting

```
<exclude wildcard="alpha" atomic="false" collection="true"/>
```

but setting `wildcard="alpha/a"` or anything similar does not seem to work. I have also tried regexp instead of wildcard and different combinations of `atomic` and `collection`, but no luck. Is my understanding correct that it is not currently possible to filter by folder and file names in one rule?

Comment: There is more discussion about this issue at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385287/regexp-for-matching-directories.  And perhaps a solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502991/1211981

Comment: Thanks, @EricBridger but I do not think there is the example for matching a full path?

Comment: You are correct, I just found a work-around which worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<exclude>` and `<include>` elements only allows to match the name, but no the full path.

P.S.: BTW, I have just made a pull request at the Thredds' GitHub repository to include this funcionality.

https://github.com/Unidata/thredds/pull/1015

Probably some tests and improvement should be reviewed.

Comment: Thanks, that's more than I expected!